# Receiving data in wrong json format from node

Tags: node.js

I send response as

```
 return httpres.status(200).send({ "Status"  :    Status_id['Status'] })
```

inside get() method, may be due to wrong headers ,I'm  receiving data in wrong json format  in client:

```
 Object { _body: "{\"Status\":222}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, type: 2, url: "http://localhost:3000/api/spf_ids/1" }
```

This is what I need

```
 {\"Status\":222}// This is wrong json format slashes are coming by default
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you set the Content-Type header to application/json.
but if you want to send it in a `object` style you can `stringify` it:

```
 return httpres.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ "Status"  :    Status_id['Status']}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return res.status(200).json({ "Status"  :    Status_id['Status'] })
```